# Gnome 3 showed panels on reboot. NOT intended! Anyone seen this before?

Tags: gnome

I rebooted after a few successful Gnome 3 reboots, but this time, I was welcomed by panels. My quickbar would not even show up when I pressed the super key. I have no idea what happened, but I think some part got reverted to Gnome 2! Please help!

ATI mobility 4200,
Ubuntu 11.10 64bit,
Gnome 3 (more or less now!)

Any help is appreciated.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Post your screenshot as a link and then someone with sufficient reputation can embed it.

Answer (score 2):

That is highly unlikely. It's more likely that you went into the fallback mode, which does provide two panels, but they don't look entirely like the ones in 11.04. It can do that because of issues with your VGA.

Comment: Is there any way to fix it? I have tried reinstalling the gnome shell, and the open source Radeon drivers.